# How can I resolve a python version error issue?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the package `conifer` on python. The steps for installation are listed on the GitHub. After following such steps, I get a python version error as shown on the image attached. Nevertheless, I am running on the version the package requires. I am thinking it could be an issue with `pip`, and I tried different things, including replacing `pip` with `pip3`. It still did not work. Thus, I am wondering if anyone here has some advice regarding this issue. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: This package requires Python version >= 3.8, not 3.7.12.

Comment: you need to use 3.8+ version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misread the error message, `3.7.12 not in ">=3.8"` means "the current version 3.7.12 does not fall in the range 'versions greater than or equal to 3.8'" - and it clearly doesn't. That required version range at the end `>=3.8` is what was defined for `conifer` and you'll see different ones for different packages, for example it could also be `==3.8` (i.e. has to be exactly 3.8) or `<3.8` (only works for versions older than 3.8)